# MVC 5 invalid JSON primitive

Tags: ajax, json, autocomplete, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to write a auto-complete with ajax in MVC5 but no matter what I try I get the error invalid JSON primitive. 
 When I enter the url manually localhost:5088/GetData?inpt=[query] I am able to see the return json.

From what I understand online , I am giving the "data:" parameter wrong. I tried putting them in "" but it didn't work.

My Controller :

```
  public  JsonResult GetData(string inpt)
        {
            try
            {
                var node = //some values here , cause its too long I deleted it 
                foreach (var node in q)
                {
                    string scity = node.Attribute("CityName").Value.ToUpper(new CultureInfo("tr-TR", false));
                    string ccity = node.Attribute("CityCode").Value;
                    string ccode = node.Attribute("CountryCode").Value;
                    if (ccity != oldcity)
                    {
                        result.Add(new HavaAlani { SehirAdi = scity, HavaAlaniKodu = ccity, HavaAlaniAdi = scity + ", " + ccode, Sehirmi = true });
                        oldcity = ccity;
                    }
                    result.Add(new HavaAlani { SehirAdi = scity, HavaAlaniKodu = node.Attribute("Code").Value, HavaAlaniAdi = node.Value, Sehirmi = false });
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }

            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

My JS :

```
    $('input.suggestBox').each(function () {
    //$(this).jsonSuggest(air.Lines);
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "dataAl/GetData",
                data: { inpt: request.term },
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataFilter: function (data) { return data; },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        return {
                            code: item.HavaAlaniKodu,
                            value: item.HavaAlaniAdi,
                            iscity: item.Sehirmi
                        }
                    }))
                },
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        var cls = "airport";
        if (item.iscity)
            cls = "city";
        return $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<span class='span-" + cls + "'></span>")
                .append("<a class='ui-autocomplete-" + cls + "'>" + item.value + " (" + item.code + ")" + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
    };

});
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the JSON Returned?

Comment: It doesnt return JSOn , it gives warning "invalid JSOn primitive:inpt." But it gives the error in html format within title tag of head

Comment: hmm... That is strange, I though that particular error originated with jquery, not MVC. If you put a break point in that action does it appear to complete? If not can you also show where result is declared. Also try changing DataType to "text json" or "text/json"

Comment: Added to answer - I believe you need to stringify your data object as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Comment was getting a bit long so adding this as an answer-

The first thing to try would be modifying your content type per this post:
[MVC JSON method returning invalid JSON to JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824849/mvc-json-method-returning-invalid-json-to-jquery)

Try "application/json".

also wrap your data object in

```
  JSON.stringify()
```

If that doesn't work can you tell me where result is coming from in your action - I'm not seeing the declaration. Also add a break point and ensure that you can step into that method.

Comment: After setting a breakpoint in System.Web.MVC.JSONValueProviderFactory, I found that my 'application/json' POST data had been url-encoded by jQuery/ajax. To prevent this, add the option `processData: false` to your request and take @Kelly Gendron's advice and call stringify on your object as well. MVC looks for the 'application/json' option and expects it to be a regular json string that it then deserializes.

Comment: example:
`$.ajax({
 type : 'POST',
 contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 url : 'equipment/GetData',
 data : JSON.stringify({
  "start" : $("#startTime").val(),
  "end" : $("#endTime").val(),
  "name" : "name"
 }),
 processData : false,
 dataType : 'application/json'
})
`